# mysql event schedular to schedule event every day 8am

Tags: php, mysql, sql, events, scheduler

I checked event scheduler is off on my phpmyadmin. My site is live, i dont know making event scheduler `on` can create any bad effect ?

I want to create event which should execute every morning, fetch some value from table and show on the page.

```
CREATE EVENT rate ON SCHEDULE EVERY 24 HOUR STARTS '2011-12-01 8:00:00' DO BEGIN

END
```

query I want to execute inside event is :

```
SELECT url,sentiment, count(url) from userpost where userid='".$userid."' group by url order by count(url) desc;
```

I am confused.

Event will be created on phpmyadmin. query should be executed on php page to get the values to be shown on the page.

how can manage this scenario?

Comment: I have not read on the subject in-depth, however I should not see why it would have any side effects if it were `on`; if anything, it would just look for the event you created and run it. You can also cancel that event also. Yet, I don't quite understand what you're asking exactly. You posted code for an event schedule, yet it is presently set to `off`. Can you elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: @Fred-ii-: thanks dude. actually I am exploring mysql event shedular. Just want to make sure that using it in place should not affect negatively on other existing db system

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with `phpMyAdmin` which is a client tool and there is no such thing as ***phpmyadmin server***. There is MySQL Server. Therefore please retag your question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the state of [**event_scheduler**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events-configuration.html) variable to `ON`.

Run below query on phpmyadmin

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

**EDIT::**

You have to create a php page that can be called by windows scheduler every day at 8 AM and then on your page you can directly call your query. You can't use mysql event scheduler to perform this action. You can do it with windows scheduler or some other applications.

Comment: that is ok, I knew it. problem with me is how can I use above mentioned event so that I cant fetch records from db every morning and show them on my page. I am muddled with step by step action I need to carry out

Comment: thanks, I am looking something similar, can you please reference any example?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're a little bit confused on the purpose of MySQL events or any event scheduler for that matter. It's used for **batch** processing and has no means to return any resultset to the client on its own.

> [CREATE EVENT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-event.html)
>   Statements such as SELECT or SHOW that merely return a
>   result set **have no effect when used in an event; the output from these
>   is not sent to the MySQL Monitor, nor is it stored anywhere**. However,
>   you can use statements such as SELECT ... INTO and INSERT INTO ...
>   SELECT that store a result. (See the next example in this section for
>   an instance of the latter.)

Now if you need to execute your query from the php page then go ahead and do that.

On the other hand if you want to pre-calculate some resultset(s), which is(are) resource intensive, you can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ...` syntax and an event to execute it and store results in a table. And then from php page just fetch and present them from that table.

Comment: thanks. I gone through the link. you said "it does not mean to return any resultset". I am apologize but if that is the case then how "hour based or daily based" record are shown on the page? I think that is done using event schedular only on the database

Comment: @petern: select and insert I can always do. But what if I want fetch few parameters(which gets updated by time) every hour and show them on page ..

Comment: *how "hour based or daily based" record are shown on the page* It depends on how your page is developed. You may execute your query and render your page with results, you may have an AJAX call from your page to some RESTfull service, which may be implemented in php, that executes the query and returns results (e.g. in JSON format) and you render them...

Comment: @petern: "RESTfull services"  like?

Comment: *"RESTfull services" like?* For starters you can read [How to build a secure and RESTful service in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5816233/1920232)